# Setting Kendo UI grid height 100% on MOBILE

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I am trying to set a kendo grid height to 100% . I did it before on a regular mvc project and its work ok but it is not working on mobile. Here what I am doing:

http://dojo.telerik.com/UVuDe

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using `data-stretch="true"` on the view?
http://dojo.telerik.com/IKOLe

Comment: Thank You !! I thought I had trying with `data- stretch = "true"`, but obviously I was wrong. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

well this piece of code seems to work in your dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/UVuDe/4:

```
function gridResize(size){

    if (size == null || size == undefined) {
        size = 0.6;
    }
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    windowHeight = windowHeight * size;
    $(".k-grid-content").height(windowHeight);

  }
```

I do have something a bit more generic/more configurable in another project if this doesn't work for you.

This will put the grid contents at a size of 60% of window's screen height in it's default state but you can configure this for your own needs.

Hopefully this gives you a starting place.

Any issues/changes you require let me know.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your help. Your code works, but I must to scroll to see the footer of the grid if I set the size in 1 like this gridResize(1).I want the grid fills the view.

Comment: Well this code is intended to resize the "row" sections ie the inner content of the grid. By setting it 1 you are obviously setting the inner content to 100% of the screen height. So adjusting it to say .90 or something like that may give you the desired effect. is the grid going to be on the screen by itself or is it going to have other things as you then have to account for off setting the size by what ever other elements are on the screen which starts to get complicated unless you split the screen into 2 or more sections that you can reference